# Changing range of bitwise counting loop

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, countdown, bit-shift

I struggle with bitwise operations/mathematics so I'm hoping someone can help me here. I have a counting loop that initially decrements from 15 to 0 and then back to again by way of four LED bit variables. I'm trying to have one variable that will allow me to decrease the range of this count and still maintain the functionality of the LED variables. This is what I have:

```
int counter = 15
range = 15; // input to modify the counting loop range

// each second..
counter = (counter - 1) % 16;
led0 = (counter >> 0) & 1;
led1 = (counter >> 1) & 1;
led2 = (counter >> 2) & 1;
led3 = (counter >> 3) & 1;
```

I'd like it so that changing `range` to say, 7, would turn `led3` off and proceed to loop the counter through only the range 0-7. Is there a simple fix for this or am I going to have to start from scratch and devise a new way?

Comment: where are you using the "range" variable?

Comment: I'm not yet, that's an input to the function. I just put it there to try to explain the functionality I'm trying to add.

Comment: Isn't it as simple as `counter = (counter - 1) % (range + 1);` ?

Comment: Ahh, I think that's all it is. Thank you.